# error C2593: 'operator =' is ambiguous; Compiled fine on VS6, but I get that error on VS10

Tags: c++

I get the following error:

```
1>c:\documents and settings\krzys\desktop\desktop icons\ollydbg\plugins\odbgscript\OllyLangCommands.cpp(3602): error C2593: 'operator =' is ambiguous
1>          c:\documents and settings\krzys\desktop\desktop icons\ollydbg\plugins\odbgscript\var.h(45): could be 'var &var::operator =(const long double &)'
1>          c:\documents and settings\krzys\desktop\desktop icons\ollydbg\plugins\odbgscript\var.h(42): or       'var &var::operator =(const int &)'
1>          c:\documents and settings\krzys\desktop\desktop icons\ollydbg\plugins\odbgscript\var.h(41): or       'var &var::operator =(const ulong &)'
1>          while trying to match the argument list '(var, std::streamsize)'
```

At this code:

```
map<string, var> variables;
streamsize sum = 0;

if (sum) {
    variables["$RESULT"] = sum;  // Error 1
    return true;
}
```

and

```
class var
{
public:
 ulong dw;
 string str;
 long double flt;
 vtype vt;
 bool isbuf;
 int size;

 var();
 var(const var& rhs); 
 var(string& rhs); 
 var(ulong rhs); 
 var(int rhs); 
 var(long double rhs); 

 // less than zero this < rhs
 // zero this == rhs 
 // greater than zero this > rhs 
 int compare(const var& rhs) const; 
 int compare(const string& rhs) const; 
 int compare(const ulong& rhs) const; 
 int compare(const int& rhs) const; 
 int compare(const long double& rhs) const; 

 string strclean(void);
 string strbuffhex(void);
 string strbuff(void);

 var& operator=(const var& rhs);
 var& operator=(const string& rhs);
 var& operator=(const ulong& rhs); // Error 4
 var& operator=(const int& rhs); // Error 3
 var& operator=(unsigned short& rhs);
 var& operator=(unsigned char& rhs);
 var& operator=(const long double& rhs); // Error 2

 var& operator+=(const var& rhs);
 var& operator+=(const string& rhs);
 var& operator+=(const ulong& rhs);
 var& operator+=(const int& rhs);
 var& operator+=(const long double& rhs);

 void resize(ulong newsize);

};
```

Compiled perfectly with VS6, but now I'm getting this error with VS10.

Comment: So, how 'bout those `operator=` definitions? What is `sum`? What is `variables`? How shall we fix code with no code?

Comment: A bit more code might be nice - at least the types/declarations for `sum` and `variables`.

Comment: Whoops, sorry.  Anyway, I might as well just give you everything. It's line 3602: http://pastebin.com/p7TMQTgQ

Comment: Giving us everything is a poor way to solve a problem. That's *tons* of code (code smell, by the way), and though I didn't read the whole thing I don't think you even gave us the definition for the class and therefore `variables`. *Trim* the problem to something manageable; you'll probably solve it yourself that way. Otherwise, I reiterate what I said above.

Comment: My bad, I thought it would all be there.  Anyway, map<string, var> variables; and streamsize sum = 0;  I still don't see what's wrong though.

Comment: This form is much better, by the way, and it's actually a well-written and complete question.  +1 for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `variables` map holds values of type `var`. `sum` isn't a `var`, so a conversion needs to be made.

The `streamsize` type in VC6 is a simple `int` and the `var` class will convert that to a `var` type implicitly.

In VS10, `streamsize` is an `__int64`, which you have no implicit conversion to a `var` for.

Answer (score 5):

Check sum's type and variables's methods. There's a chance they've added new operator= overloads in the switch from VS6 to VS2010.