# error C2593; Program compiles under VS6 but not under VS10

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [error C2593: 'operator =' is ambiguous; Compiled fine on VS6, but I get that error on VS10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3848527/error-c2593-operator-is-ambiguous-compiled-fine-on-vs6-but-i-get-that-erro)

I get the following error:

```
1>c:\documents and settings\krzys\desktop\desktop icons\ollydbg\plugins\odbgscript\OllyLangCommands.cpp(3602): error C2593: 'operator =' is ambiguous
1>          c:\documents and settings\krzys\desktop\desktop icons\ollydbg\plugins\odbgscript\var.h(45): could be 'var &var::operator =(const long double &)'
1>          c:\documents and settings\krzys\desktop\desktop icons\ollydbg\plugins\odbgscript\var.h(42): or       'var &var::operator =(const int &)'
1>          c:\documents and settings\krzys\desktop\desktop icons\ollydbg\plugins\odbgscript\var.h(41): or       'var &var::operator =(const ulong &)'
1>          while trying to match the argument list '(var, std::streamsize)'
```

At this code:

```
map<string, var> variables;
streamsize sum = 0;

if (sum) {
    variables["$RESULT"] = sum;  // Error 1
    return true;
}
```

and

```
class var
{
public:
 ulong dw;
 string str;
 long double flt;
 vtype vt;
 bool isbuf;
 int size;

 var();
 var(const var& rhs); 
 var(string& rhs); 
 var(ulong rhs); 
 var(int rhs); 
 var(long double rhs); 

 // less than zero this < rhs
 // zero this == rhs 
 // greater than zero this > rhs 
 int compare(const var& rhs) const; 
 int compare(const string& rhs) const; 
 int compare(const ulong& rhs) const; 
 int compare(const int& rhs) const; 
 int compare(const long double& rhs) const; 

 string strclean(void);
 string strbuffhex(void);
 string strbuff(void);

 var& operator=(const var& rhs);
 var& operator=(const string& rhs);
 var& operator=(const ulong& rhs); // Error 4
 var& operator=(const int& rhs); // Error 3
 var& operator=(unsigned short& rhs);
 var& operator=(unsigned char& rhs);
 var& operator=(const long double& rhs); // Error 2

 var& operator+=(const var& rhs);
 var& operator+=(const string& rhs);
 var& operator+=(const ulong& rhs);
 var& operator+=(const int& rhs);
 var& operator+=(const long double& rhs);

 void resize(ulong newsize);

};
```

Compiled perfectly with VS6, but now I'm getting this error with VS10.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3848527/error-c2593-operator-is-ambiguous-compiled-fine-on-vs6-but-i-get-that-erro. Edit your old question with this info, don't ask an entirely "new" question. I've done that for you. This should be closed.

Comment: Didn't know how so I reorganized my main post and just made a new one.

Comment: There's an edit button under your post. You might take a minute to read the FAQ and Editing FAQ (upper right hand side of Answer Field, for example) to familiarize yourself with things before you use them.